# The rectangle on opencv face detection doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv

Im Working on a simple face-detection script with the opencv package for python.

it detect my face in the image but the end result doesn't shows the rectangle around it.

here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time


img = cv2.imread('29404037_277543452823162_5856458151733231616_n.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = np.array(gray, dtype=np.uint8)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

print('Faces found: ', len(faces))

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
   cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

what may be the problem ?

Comment: try printing `(x, y, w, h)` and see if it fits the image size

Comment: Remove the line `img = np.array(gray, dtype=np.uint8)`. And also, see if `faces` array contains valid rectangles or is empty?

Comment: can you show the image.. and try following this Tutorial https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html